# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver after ant build.xml

Tags: java, mariadb, build.xml

I am creating jar and trying to execute the jar but its giving

```
C:\Users\xyz\workspace\ACS-AD\target>java -jar ExtractADData.jar
Current dir:C:\Users\xyz\workspace\ACS-AD\target
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
 Search error: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ACSSUsers_Mariadb.truncateACSSADStage(Unknown Source)
        at com.ExtractADData.main(Unknown Source)
```

Its because of referenced jar not adding while building jar, so can I give java -cp "jar" Extract.jar or is there any other way to avoid this .. like forming jar with all dependency jars ? If so how to add it in build.xml ?

Comment: use `mariadb-java-client.jar` . if it there check it's loaded on the class path

Comment: yah I have it but build.xml not including it I guess.. Do anyone help in adding dependency jar properly in build.xml so that the above error may go off?